# Does a thread die when its parent is dead?

Tags: multithreading

Does a thread die once I kill the program which started it?

Probably it has to do with my English, but I couldn't find it here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Comment: It couldn't be there, because it isn't related to python at all. When you kill program/process the OS will free all resources related with them.

Comment: You should refer to the core [thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html) docs instead, which says `When the main thread exits, it is system defined whether the other threads survive. On SGI IRIX using the native thread implementation, they survive. On most other systems, they are killed without executing try ... finally clauses or executing object destructors.`

Comment: Thanks georg very appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when a process is [killed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) (e.g. by sending it [`SiGKILL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGKILL)), all of its threads get terminated.

It's worth noting that this is not Python-specific.

Comment: Just as a side note. This is not specific to Python but in general, if a parent is closed, then its threads close as well. With forks, its a whole other issue.

Comment: Sorry, but that's rubbish. Only the initial thread of a process is special, all others are equal and there is in particular no parent-child relation between threads. Further, even the behaviour when the initial thread terminates is not consistent across systems, as @georg above mentioned. If you wanted to say that terminating a process involves killing all of its threads, then that is true, but that's a different thing.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Wait, which part of what is rubbish? All my answer is saying is that killing a process (e.g. by sending it a [`SIGKILL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGKILL)), all of its threads get terminated. Which part of that is controversial?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Also note that neither the question nor the answer mention any notion of parent/child relationship between *threads*. The question is clearly talking (in somewhat vague terms) about a thread and the process it's part of.

Comment: In general this is wrong. It's specific to Linux, and only accidentally accurate on Windows, whereas the question is about Python. And from Python point of view it's OS specific. There is no guarantee that it will always behave as on Linux.

Comment: Sorry, @NPE, my comment was aimed at the (IMHO misleading) response by Games Brainiac. Then, you are right, the question doesn't talk about parent-child relations between threads. However, it does talk about a parent, but fails to specify whether a parent process or a parent thread is meant.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I agree, the wording is a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [this is the part of the documentation you're looking for](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#module-thread), and it states:

> When the main thread exits, it is system defined whether the other threads survive. On SGI IRIX using the native thread implementation, they survive. On most other systems, they are killed without executing try ... finally clauses or executing object destructors.

So it's a thing Python doesn't define - it can vary depending on the particular OS.